# Вывод текста песни с отступами

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Хочу в программе выводить текст песни по куплетам ну типа так:

строка1
строка2

строка3
строка4

Как лучше занести такой текст в БД, чтобы легче было потом форматировать? БД SQLite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это типичная задача на составление своего языка разметки. Идеально подойдет XML, типа:

```
<song>
   <title>Пусть всегда будет солнце</title>
   <couplet>
      <verse>Солнечный круг</verse>
      <verse>Небо вокруг</verse>
   </couplet>
</song>
```

Согласен, что избыточно. Но вдруг вы решите потом к нему ноты пририсовать? Тогда будет уже неизбыточно.

Другой вариант (дешевый) завершать строки символом `\n` и распознавать это как конец строфы/куплета ну и т.д.

Comment: так и сделал. добавил в конец \n, но думал кто-то предложит более лучшее решение. Спасибо :)

Comment: А чем не нравится XML?

Comment: c xml в андроид не работал никогда. Я новичок. С json немного умею только работать.

Comment: Интересует вариант добавления нот. @Barmaley Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: И всё-таки не понятен процесс занесения текста песни в БД.